Issue using ConfirmDialog and Toasts alongside EditForm
Good morning. I hope you can help me.
I am trying to use the ConfirmDialog and Toasts components.
If I run it from any component, it works perfectly:
Example:
    @page "/counter"
    @rendermode InteractiveServer

    <PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

    <h1>Counter</h1>

    <p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount1">Click Toasts</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount2">Click ConfirmDialog</button>

    @if (toastParametros.Visible){<_Toast toastParametros="toastParametros"></_Toast>} 

    <ConfirmDialog @ref="confirmDialog" />


    @code {
        private int currentCount = 0;
        private ToastParametros toastParametros = new ToastParametros(); 
        private ConfirmDialog confirmDialog;

        private void IncrementCount()
        {
            currentCount++;
        }
        private void IncrementCount1()
        {

                toastParametros.Type = ToastType.Info;
                toastParametros.IconName = IconName.Alarm;
                toastParametros.Title = "title";
                toastParametros.Message = $"info saved.";

                toastParametros.Visible = true;
        }


        private void IncrementCount2()
        {

             var confirmation = confirmDialog.ShowAsync("Confir", "¿save the changes?");

        }
    }

The problem occurs when I use EditForm, as neither ConfirmDialog nor Toasts become visible, despite being invoked. When you click the save button, the browser remains "loading."
Example Code:
@page "/prueba"
<!-- Form Fields Here -->

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <Button Color="ButtonColor.Success" Size="ButtonSize.Medium" Type="ButtonType.Submit" >
        <Icon CustomIconName="fas fa-save" /> Save
    </Button>
    <Button Color="ButtonColor.Secondary" Size="ButtonSize.Medium" Type="ButtonType.Link">
        <Icon CustomIconName="fas fa-times" /> go back
    </Button>
   </div>
</div>

<ConfirmDialog @ref="dialog" />

@code {
    private ConfirmDialog dialog = default!;
    private Cliente Model = new Cliente();

    private async Task HandleSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
    try
    {
    if (context.Validate())
    {
    var confirmation = await ShowConfirmation();
    if (confirmation)
    {
    await Insert(Model);
    }
    }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ShowConfirmation()
    {
        var options = new ConfirmDialogOptions
        {
            YesButtonText = "OK",
            NoButtonText = "Cancelar"
        };

        return await dialog.ShowAsync("Confirmar", "¿Confirma los cambios?", options);
    }

    private async Task Insert(Cliente cliente)
    {
        // Your insert logic here
    }


    public class Cliente
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}


**I can't solve it, I can't find error(s) in the browser console, nor in the debugging console.**


Who's components are you trying to use?

Here is the simple sample i have created to use the ConfirmDialog and Toasts you could try to use at your side:
Prueba.razor:
@page "/prueba"
@using BlazorApp1.Components
@using BlazorApp1.Models

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="HandleSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <InputText id="name" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="age">Age</label>
        <InputNumber id="age" class="form-control" @bind-Value="Model.Age" />
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                <i class="fas fa-times"></i> Go Back
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<ConfirmDialog @ref="dialog" />
<Toast @ref="toast" />

@code {
    private ConfirmDialog dialog = default!;
    private Toast toast = default!;
    private Cliente Model = new Cliente();

    private async Task HandleSubmit()
    {
        var confirmation = await ShowConfirmation();
        if (confirmation)
        {
            await Insert(Model);
            ShowToast("Success", "Data saved successfully!");
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> ShowConfirmation()
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        await dialog.ShowAsync(
            "Confirmar",
            "¿Confirma los cambios?",
            async () => tcs.SetResult(true),
            async () => tcs.SetResult(false)
        );

        return await tcs.Task;
    }

    private void ShowToast(string title, string message)
    {
        toast.Show(title, message);
    }

    private async Task Insert(Cliente cliente)
    {
        // Simulate data insertion
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}

ConfirmDialog.razor:
@code {
    public Func<Task> OnConfirm { get; set; }
    public Func<Task> OnCancel { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; } = "Confirm";
    public string Message { get; set; } = "Are you sure?";
    public string YesButtonText { get; set; } = "Yes";
    public string NoButtonText { get; set; } = "No";

    public async Task ShowAsync(string title, string message, Func<Task> confirmCallback, Func<Task> cancelCallback)
    {
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        OnConfirm = confirmCallback;
        OnCancel = cancelCallback;
        IsVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task Confirm()
    {
        IsVisible = false;
        if (OnConfirm != null) await OnConfirm.Invoke();
    }

    private async Task Cancel()
    {
        IsVisible = false;
        if (OnCancel != null) await OnCancel.Invoke();
    }
}
@if (IsVisible)
{
    <div class="modal" style="display:block">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>@Title</h4>
            <p>@Message</p>
            <button @onclick="Confirm">@YesButtonText</button>
            <button @onclick="Cancel">@NoButtonText</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

Toast.razor:
<div class="toast" style="position: fixed; bottom: 20px; right: 20px; display: @(IsVisible ? "block" : "none"); background-color: #333; color: white; padding: 15px; border-radius: 5px;">
    <h4>@Title</h4>
    <p>@Message</p>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    [Parameter] public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsVisible { get; private set; }

    public void Show(string title, string message)
    {
        Title = title;
        Message = message;
        IsVisible = true;
        StateHasChanged();

        // Automatically hide the toast after 3 seconds
        _ = HideAfterDelayAsync();
    }

    private async Task HideAfterDelayAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); // Wait for 3 seconds
        Hide();
    }

    public void Hide()
    {
        IsVisible = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

Cliente.cs:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BlazorApp1.Models
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required.")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 120, ErrorMessage = "Age must be between 1 and 120.")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
}

so, overview is I have used the button instead of the submit in EditForm.


